# Explicitly declared property doesn't exist, typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a simple component, but for some reason a property that has been explicitly defined doesn't exist on that same component. I've tried changing the name to something else with no luck.

```
enum ButtonSize {
  large = "large",
  medium = "medium",
  small = "small",
}
function Button({
  className,
  children,
  color,
  size, // <= Error
  ...props
}: DetailedHTMLProps<
  ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>,
  HTMLButtonElement & { size: ButtonSize } & ColorScheme

>)
```

It outputs:

> Property 'size' does not exist on type
> 'ClassAttributes<HTMLButtonElement & { size: ButtonSize; } &
> ColorScheme> & ButtonHTMLAttributes'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing the `&`'s in the wrong place. They should be *after* DetailedHTMLProps, not inside it:

```
DetailedHTMLProps<
  ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>,
  HTMLButtonElement
> & { size: ButtonSize } & ColorScheme
```

Comment: Yes, that  was it, thank you. For some reason ColorScheme worked fine so that threw me off. I thought those should be added on top of the HTMLButtonElement